# Node Express Session not being saved

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to get sessions working with node. Im using Express 4.8.7. Im following th tutorial [here](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/).

I have built an API in node running on port 8080. I have an Angular app running on port 8081.

At the top of my server.js file i have:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

var sess;
```

When I login, I do:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    var successCallback = function(res, status, content) {

        sess = req.session;
        sess.email = req.body.email;

        console.log('in LOGIN and req.session is ', req.session);

        sendJsonResponse(res, status, content);
    }

    ctrlUsers.signin(req, res, successCallback);

});
```

And after login, the frontend does a request to a /files endpoint:

```
app.get('/files', function(req, res){

     console.log('in files route and req.session is ', req.session);

 });
```

In the example I have linked to above, the req.session should contain a property with the email address. But it doesnt, it just contains:

```
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Any ideas why the session isn't getting saved correctly?

Answer (score -1):

change

```
app.get('/files', function(req, res){

     console.log('in files route and req.session is ', req.session);

 });
```

to ==>

```
var usersession = req.session;
app.get('/files', function(req, res){

     console.log('in files route and req.session is ', usersession);

 });
```